# Этимология слова "расфуфыренный"

Tags: этимология

Расфуфыренный - ярко, броско одетый, надутый, разодетый. А вот интересно было бы узнать, откуда это слово вообще взялось?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Я знаю что похожее слова фря -- пренебрежительное "фрау" вся из себя разодетая. Может оттуда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фу !  – звук выдыхаемого воздуха,  вздох усталости и удовлетворения. Двойное « фуфу» -  это уже дым и иллюзия или чепуха, которая мало что стоит.  Или  воздушная легкомысленность, или надувательство-обман.

Например: 
Теперешнее наступление Колчака на Волгу ведется оно без солидной подготовки, на фуфу.  Вы прежде поднимете всем этим на фуфу предводителя, и пока он будет почитать вас богачом, вы женитесь на его дочери. И кончено, и все кончено! Свадьба пошла на фуфу..

В ненормативной лексике фуфель,  фуфло – это подделка.

И наконец, фуфыря/фуфыра, которая  надувается, превозноситься, много мнит о себе. И одевается  слишком нарядно, крикливо или безвкусно.  «Ишь фуфыря, расфуфырилась"!

Comment: Много мнит о себе, разодетая как буржуазия это фря -- пренебрежительное название фрау в простонародье.